# App crashes with output : "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) "

Tags: ios

The issue appears to arise when I connect the outlets to the storyboard. If I don't have them connected, I can run the app and it runs - without showing anything in the table. However, when connecting the outlets it brings up the error.

```
2014-11-19 15:35:45.477 To Do 2[2786:34838] -[To_Do_2.FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b660fd0
2014-11-19 15:35:45.488 To Do 2[2786:34838] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[To_Do_2.FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b660fd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00212946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01beea97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0021a5c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
3   CoreFoundation                      0x001633e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00162fae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIKit                               0x00d0237f -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2803
6   UIKit                               0x00d0673a -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 98
7   UIKit                               0x00b31650 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 175
8   UIKit                               0x00b30b79 -[UITableView reloadData] + 1782
9   UIKit                               0x00b3532e -[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 78
10  UIKit                               0x00b3b317 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 36
11  UIKit                               0x00ab0dd1 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608
12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c04771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
13  QuartzCore                          0x0469c28f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
14  QuartzCore                          0x04690115 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397
15  QuartzCore                          0x0469e5f6 -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 44
16  UIKit                               0x00aa2d52 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 710
17  UIKit                               0x00aa2a77 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutIfNeeded] + 83
18  UIKit                               0x00bc32a6 -[UITabBarController _layoutViewController:] + 312
19  UIKit                               0x00bc3451 -[UITabBarController _wrapperViewForViewController:] + 248
20  UIKit                               0x00bcb43e -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 454
21  UIKit                               0x00bcaa62 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
22  UIKit                               0x00bc6c55 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 340
23  UIKit                               0x00bc6ad7 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 193
24  UIKit                               0x00bc36a2 __87-[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:]_block_invoke + 43
25  UIKit                               0x00aa77af +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
26  UIKit                               0x00bc354f -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 244
27  UIKit                               0x00bc43a6 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 148
28  UIKit                               0x00b816e1 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 545
29  UIKit                               0x00b81c5a -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 148
30  UIKit                               0x00b82fab -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 395
31  UIKit                               0x00aa12a8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 662
32  UIKit                               0x00aad92a -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 511
33  UIKit                               0x00aa086e -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
34  UIKit                               0x00a749e3 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 512
35  UIKit                               0x00a74c99 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 287
36  UIKit                               0x00a74f50 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
37  UIKit                               0x00a8328d -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
38  UIKit                               0x00a20776 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3108
39  UIKit                               0x00a23c0d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
40  UIKit                               0x00a3c7d0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
41  UIKit                               0x00a2281f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
42  FrontBoardServices                  0x035fe9de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
43  FrontBoardServices                  0x035fe46f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
44  FrontBoardServices                  0x03610425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
45  CoreFoundation                      0x001361c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
46  CoreFoundation                      0x0012bad3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
47  CoreFoundation                      0x0012b92b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
48  CoreFoundation                      0x0012abcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
49  CoreFoundation                      0x0012a9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
50  UIKit                               0x00a221e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
51  UIKit                               0x00a258b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
52  To Do 2                             0x0002d7fe top_level_code + 78
53  To Do 2                             0x0002d83b main + 43
54  libdyld.dylib                       0x0235bac9 start + 1
55  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: check your 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' method

Comment: post your code here then only yo will get

Comment: you will get some solution

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is here:

```
[To_Do_2.FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]
```

You are not telling how many `rows` each `section` need to have.
You may need to post your code.